# Ruby plugin for web browser?

Tags: javascript, ruby, browser, frontend

Am I correct that if someone wrote a Ruby plugin for a web browser and a user installed that plugin then it would be possible to replace javascript with ruby on the frontend?

Aren't there any plugins for this? Or even for using other languages than javascript on the browser side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use http://ironruby.net/ in a Silverlight Plugin, but I have not a clue about how easy DOM interaction is this way.

But I **BEG YOU** don't do it! Please, use the Open Web Stack to solve your problems.
If you don't leave your Ruby world of comfort, you will not only hurt your users experience *"WTF? Why do I need Silverlight for this page?"* but you will also get stuck in your small little Ruby world without learning anything new and exciting.

It would be better for both of you, if you'd just go ahead and learn JavaScript.

Because remember: *"Learning is a good thing!"*

Comment: Plugins can introduce immense security leaks and performance problems. Take for instance the flash plugin, which is too processor intensive to run properly on mobile phones and has a patch at regular intervals to close a dangerous security leak. JavaScript IS the language of the browser, if anything, look for a Ruby to JavaScript compiler.

Answer (score 2):

One thing is A FACT: as of 2010 JavaScript does not have a thread stopping "sleep" function (other than the one that just burns CPU cycles).

I have been working with JavaScript for at least a year before posting this comment and I have come to a conclusion that the lack of a thread-stopping sleep function is a real show-stopper for threading related code.

A consequence of the lack of the sleep function is that it's not possible to simulate a Ruby/C#/C++/etc. like threading model in JavaScript, which in turn means that it's not possible to translate any of the threading enabled languages to JavaScript, no matter, what one does, unless the JavaScript is supplemented with a (preferably non-CPU-cycle-burning) sleep function.

If one surfs around, then one can find many comments that state that the sleep function is not even necessary, that the setTimeout is sufficient, etc.,  but I guess that people, who state that, have not tried to implement a threading framework in JavaScript. (Think of mutexes, critical sections. I refuse to go into a discussion that the critical sections/synchronization are/is not necessary for cases, where widget content consists of multiple data components that form an "atomic whole".)

The second show-stopper for the whole DOM-model is the implementation that renders DOM elements IN THE BACKGROUND THREAD.

Here's, what happens:

In Javascript:
       create_my_awsome_widget_in_DOM();
       edit_my_awsome_widget_by_editing_DOM_inside_it()
       if_we_are_lucky_we_reach_here_without_crashing_the_app()

As the DOM is rendered in background (read: in a separate thread), there will be a race condition between the thread that initiated the DOM editing, by making a call to the create_my_awsome_widget_in_DOM(), and the DOM rendering. If the rendering thread is "quick enough" to render the DOM before the JavasSript thread calls the edit_my_awsome_widget_by_editing_DOM_inside_it(), everything works fine, but if it's the other way around, then the JavaScript starts to modify region of the DOM that does not (yet) exist.

Essentially it means that due to the background DOM rendering the        create_my_awsome_widget_in_DOM() and edit_my_awsome_widget_by_editing_DOM_inside_it() are executed in a random order and obviously the application crashes, if the edit_my_awsome_widget_by_editing_DOM_inside_it() is called before the create_my_awsome_widget_in_DOM().

Comment: Actually, may be there is a way to simulate a proper sleep() in JavaScript.

As of 01.2011 I don't know, if it works, but may be, if one "overrides the function class", let's say, by wrapping all application-level function calls to instances that one has self designed, and uses "self-made virtual threads", one might get a proper sleep() simulation without burning CPU cycles.

However, it could be a hoke, because, as I said, as of January 2011 I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to do it indirectly. [Here is the original presentation](http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/a-wonderful-awful-idea-ruby-in-the-browser.html) at RubyConf 2008. The topic:

> This talk is about the many paths towards getting ruby running in your web browser. I'll first talk about why this is even a good idea. I'll then talk briefly about each approach I've investigated and the differing amounts of FAIL I encountered with each. Next I'll focus on the most promising contender, rubyjs, a ruby compiler which outputs javascript.

The project rubyjs [still exists](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyjs/), but it appears to be dead. The idea probably was a little too crazy.

Answer (score 1):

**mruby** seems like an interesting option for running ruby in a web browser:
http://qiezi.me/projects/mruby-web-irb/mruby.html

It's not a typical plugin as it does not require installation, it's javascript (compiled from C) running ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

Technically that would be correct, assuming the browser/plugin also provided an extensive API to deal with the DOM and such. I am not aware of any plugins that make this possible, but it's an interesting idea.